# Changing innerHTML of a paragraph to a variable returning NaN

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to set up a timer that uses setInterval(), where every 1000 milliseconds a variable is incremented by 1. To test and see if this works, I have tried to set up a simple paragraph with an id, and change the innerHTML to the variable timer, which should count up to 1,2,3 etc. But whenever the code runs, the paragraph displays NaN, and I am not sure why. Can anyone help?

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload=autoTrafficLight()>

<p id="msg">0</p>

<table border="10px" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" id="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" id="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);" id="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
var timer = 0
function autoTrafficLight() {
    setInterval(function() { 
        var timer = timer + 1;      
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = +timer
    }, 1000)

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you can replace the stuff in the setInterval with just `timer += 1; document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = timer;`. Oh, and have you made a decision to omit semicolons?

Answer (score 1):

You are redeclaring the timer variable, so essentially you were trying to add undefined and 1 together. timer = timer+1; will fix or timer++;

```
var timer = 0
function autoTrafficLight() {
    setInterval(function() { 
        timer = timer + 1;      
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = timer
    }, 1000)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

JS Fiddle Link : [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manishghec/c3Loqsjk/)

define timer as global variable.

```
var timer = 0
function autoTrafficLight() {
    setInterval(function() { 
        timer = timer + 1;  
        console.log(timer);
        document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = timer;
    }, 1000)

}
```